# regular expression using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

***Input csv file:***

```
_id,field_name,field_friendly_name,purpose_of_use,category,data_source,schema,table,attribute_type,sample_values,mask_it,is_included_in_report
5e95a49b0985567430f8fc00,FullName,,,,,,,,,,
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef16,xyz,,,,,,,,,,
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef17,FullNm,,,,,,,,,,
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef18,FirstName,,,,,,,,,,
5e95a49b0985567430f8fc01,abc,,,,,,,,,,
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef19,FirstNm,,,,,,,,,,
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef20,LastName,,,,,,,,,,
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef21,LastNm,,,,,,,,,,
5e95a49b0985567430f8fc02,LegalName,,,,,,,,,,
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef22,LegalNm,,,,,,,,,,
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef23,NickName,,,,,,,,,,
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef24,pqr,,,,,,,,,,
5e95a49b0985567430f8fc03,NickNm,,,,,,,,,,
```

***regex csv table:***

```
Personal_Inforamtion,regex,addiitional_grep
Full Name,full|name|nm|txt|dsc,full
First Name,first|name|nm|txt|dsc,first
Last Name,last|name|nm|txt|dsc,last
Legal Name,legal|name|nm|txt|dsc,legal
Nick Name,nick|name|nm|txt|dsc,nick
```

***My code***

*Inlclude python modules*

```
import pandas as pd
import re
```

*Define dataframe from a csv file*

`df = pd.read_csv("Default-Profile.csv")`

*Replace underscore(_) & hyphen(-) on series field_name with in df*

`df.field_name = df.field_name.str.replace("[_-]", "", regex=True)`

*Change all characters to lowercase on series field_name with in df*

`df.field_name = df.field_name.str.lower()`

*define regex table*

`regex_table = pd.read_csv("regex.csv")`

*Code is to update field_friendly_name && is_included_in_report*

Find pattern in df.field_name for every regex in regex table and update column field_friendly_name with Personal_information if found correct match if not update as not_found and also update last column as True if match found if not False.

EX:
word should be made of only full|name|nm|txt|dsc and should contain full

```
Personal_Inforamtion,regex,addiitional_grep
Full Name,full|name|nm|txt|dsc,full
```

then update df as below:

```
_id,field_name,field_friendly_name,purpose_of_use,category,data_source,schema,table,attribute_type,sample_values,mask_it,is_included_in_report
5e95a49b0985567430f8fc00,FullName,Full Name,,,,,,,,,TRUE
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef16,xyz,not_found,,,,,,,,,FALSE
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef17,FullNm,Full Name,,,,,,,,,TRUE
```

***Desired output***

```
_id,field_name,field_friendly_name,purpose_of_use,category,data_source,schema,table,attribute_type,sample_values,mask_it,is_included_in_report
5e95a49b0985567430f8fc00,FullName,Full Name,,,,,,,,,TRUE
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef16,xyz,not_found,,,,,,,,,FALSE
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef17,FullNm,Full Name,,,,,,,,,TRUE
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef18,FirstName,First Name,,,,,,,,,TRUE
5e95a49b0985567430f8fc01,abc,not_found,,,,,,,,,FALSE
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef19,FirstNm,First Name,,,,,,,,,TRUE
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef20,LastName,Last Name,,,,,,,,,TRUE
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef21,LastNm,Last Name,,,,,,,,,TRUE
5e95a49b0985567430f8fc02,LegalName,Legal Name,,,,,,,,,TRUE
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef22,LegalNm,Legal Name,,,,,,,,,TRUE
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef23,NickName,NickName,,,,,,,,,TRUE
5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef24,pqr,not_found,,,,,,,,,FALSE
5e95a49b0985567430f8fc03,NickNm,NickName,,,,,,,,,TRUE
```

Comment: Please do not mark this as complex as   I'm finding it very difficult even after going through Python training multiple times, finding it very difficult..

Comment: Python experts need your help on this

Comment: A chat with someone who is expert in Python would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can create a group of regex usign the words in the last column of the
regex table file

```
(full)|(first)|(last)|(legal)|(nick)
```

You still be able to adjust the last column of the regex table to get a more specific output
with you need. You can then append the `not_found` case to the regex dataframe to prepare the
data to be used with `str.extract`, which extract groups from the first match pattern. With the
groups matches we can then get regex group index with `idxmax` over the row axis. After that,
map the information on the first column of the regex table to the **df** dataframe using the
group index information.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(df)

regxt = pd.read_csv("regex_table.csv")
print(regxt)

# append not_found item case
not_found = pd.Series(["not_found","",""], index=regxt.columns)
regxt = regxt.append(not_found, ignore_index=True)

# create regex groups with last column csv words
regxl = regxt.iloc[:, 2].to_list()
regx_grps = "|".join(["(" + i + ")" for i in regxl])

# get regex group match index
grp_match = df["field_name"].str.extract(regx_grps, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
grp_idx = (~grp_match.isnull()).idxmax(axis=1)

df["field_friendly_name"] = grp_idx.map(lambda r: regxt.loc[r, "Personal_Inforamtion"])
df["is_included_in_report"] = grp_idx.map(lambda r: str(r!=len(regxt)-1).upper())

print(df)
```

Output from **df**

```
                         _id field_name field_friendly_name ... mask_it  is_included_in_report
0   5e95a49b0985567430f8fc00   FullName           Full Name ...     NaN                   TRUE
1   5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef16        xyz           not_found ...     NaN                  FALSE
2   5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef17     FullNm           Full Name ...     NaN                   TRUE
3   5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef18  FirstName          First Name ...     NaN                   TRUE
4   5e95a49b0985567430f8fc01        abc           not_found ...     NaN                  FALSE
5   5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef19    FirstNm          First Name ...     NaN                   TRUE
6   5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef20   LastName           Last Name ...     NaN                   TRUE
7   5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef21     LastNm           Last Name ...     NaN                   TRUE
8   5e95a49b0985567430f8fc02  LegalName          Legal Name ...     NaN                   TRUE
9   5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef22    LegalNm          Legal Name ...     NaN                   TRUE
10  5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef23   NickName           Nick Name ...     NaN                   TRUE
11  5e95a4dd0985567430f9ef24        pqr           not_found ...     NaN                  FALSE
12  5e95a49b0985567430f8fc03     NickNm           Nick Name ...     NaN                   TRUE
```